# PowerShell Vs ADUC and Access to Attributes

Tags: powershell

I am able to view service account attributes but when I query them on the same workstation under the same credentials in with powershell I am only able to see a very small subset of information.

I am using the Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase

I am trying to understand what this may be due to or trouble shooting steps that can aid me in trying to determine if this is due to the workstation being locked down or AD beign locked down to where users can view in ADuc but they may not access things via script?  What settings control this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return all properties for a user - but you need to select and recall them.

Try something like:

```
Get-ADUser "aUserAccount" -Properties * -filter * | Select *
```

`-Properties *` will fetch all properties for the object (in this case a user)

`Select *` will display all properties that are currently returned.

You can also return specific properties if needed using the following:

```
Get-ADUser "someone" -properties Property1,Property2,Property3 -filter * | select *
```

See this link for the microisoft documentation on Get-ADUser:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps

Answer (score 1):

By default, `Get-ADUser` only returns a subset of properties. You can use the `-Properties` parameter to get more, or all of them.

From [the Microsoft documentation for Get-ADUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps):

> **-Properties**
>
> Specifies the properties of the output object to retrieve from the server. Use this parameter to retrieve properties that are not included in the default set.
>
> Specify properties for this parameter as a comma-separated list of names. To display all of the attributes that are set on the object, specify * (asterisk).
>
> To specify an individual extended property, use the name of the property. For properties that are not default or extended properties, you must specify the LDAP display name of the attribute.

Comment: Retrieval is good for use in the pipeline, but will still only end up displaying a selection. As Fazer87 notes, you'll need to add the | select * bit to actually display it all in the UI.

Comment: @music2myear Can you clarify? I get the same results (aside from the two summary lines -- PropertyNames and PropertyCount) in the UI whether I do `Get-ADUser "UserName" -properties *` or `Get-ADUser "UserName" -properties * | select *`.

Comment: Hmmmm, perhaps I was incorrect. I'll have to play around with my scripts to see how adjusting these two values changes things.